# vkAcquireNextImageKHR: Application has already acquired the maximum number of images

Tags: vulkan

I have written a simple triangle example which works on my machine but I got a bug report where the user was unable to run the example and got the following validation error.

> vkAcquireNextImageKHR: Application has already acquired the maximum number of images (0x1)" thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ErrorValidationFailedExt'

I create either `minImageCount + 1` or `maxImageCount` images in the swapchain.

If you are curious how I present the images you can see it  [here](https://github.com/MaikKlein/ash/blob/master/examples/src/bin/triangle.rs#L414). And [record_submit_commandbuffer](https://github.com/MaikKlein/ash/blob/master/examples/src/lib.rs#L35) if you are curious how I submit the command buffers.

The user also reported that he can run [SaschaWillems Vulkan examples](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan), so the error is most likely on my side.

The only difference that I could spot is that [SaschaWillems Vulkan examples](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan) would create N pre recorded commandbuffers where N is the number of images in the swapchain.

```
VK_CHECK_RESULT(swapChain.acquireNextImage(presentCompleteSemaphore, &currentBuffer));

// Use a fence to wait until the command buffer has finished execution before using it again
VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkWaitForFences(device, 1, &waitFences[currentBuffer], VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX));
VK_CHECK_RESULT(vkResetFences(device, 1, &waitFences[currentBuffer]));
```

Where I just rerecord a new command buffer after I have called `acquireNextImage` and I immediately wait on the command buffer fence and then I call `queuePresent`.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-wsi_extensions/xhtml/vkspec.html#vkAcquireNextImageKHR

> Let n be the total number of images in the swapchain, m be the value of VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR::minImageCount, and a be the number of presentable images that the application has currently acquired (i.e. images acquired with vkAcquireNextImageKHR, but not yet presented with vkQueuePresentKHR). vkAcquireNextImageKHR can always succeed if a ≤ n - m at the time vkAcquireNextImageKHR is called. vkAcquireNextImageKHR should not be called if a > n - m with a timeout of UINT64_MAX; in such a case, vkAcquireNextImageKHR may block indefinitely.

So in my case that would be `a > (m + 1) - m` => `a > 1` So the error seems to indicate that I call `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` too early. But I am still not quite sure why this happens.

On my machine I have no problems running the examples, nor do I get any validation errors. I also seem to be doing essentially the same thing as [SaschaWillems Vulkan examples](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan)

Also if you want to run it yourself, it requires Rust and the LunarG validation layers.

```
git clone https://github.com/MaikKlein/ash
cd examples
cargo run --bin triangle
```

API dump for the [render_loop](https://gist.github.com/MaikKlein/3654827fec85b311f6c46adffa649389)

Comment: Be careful; `maxImageCount` may be 0 (there is a warning note in the spec, that this is a common mistake). ;; Return `VK_FALSE` from your debug callback, so you get the real error code. ;; Don't expect people to understand rust and/or whatever abstraction you are using (e.g. what is `timeout` parameter in your case? WTH is `currentBuffer`?) Maybe in this case apidump would be helpful to see the **real** Vulkan usage.

Comment: @krOoze The code that I have posted is not mine, it is from https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan I also check if maxImageCount is 0. I don't ask anyone to read my code, I am just curious what could cause it. The timeout is also the max value. I'll have a look at renderdoc to generate an API dump.

Comment: Alright, I have found the source of that message:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/sdk-1.0.37/layers/core_validation.cpp#L12240 . So indeed attemting to acquire more than allowed images is the problem (or the layers are bugged; always a possibility)

Comment: @krOoze I didn't know that the API dump would be as easy as to register a new layer. I added an API dump for 1 frame of the render loop.

Comment: Yup, they did a good job with the ecosystem. So when does the error happen anyway? Second frame? After resize? Only on some platforms (you speak of some "the user", which is not very clear what the situation is)?

Comment: @krOoze I made Vulkan library for [Rust](https://github.com/MaikKlein/ash). It is just a lightweight Vulkan wrapper and I included two examples. The error got reported to me and I couldn't figure out why the error would even occur. He told me that he could run other Vulkan examples. The api dump is from my machine where the error doesn't manifest. I guess I'll wait and see if he can give me an API dump too. Then at least I have something that I can compare.

Comment: Yeah, little bit hard to debug without repro...  on the face of it does look like the acquire and present is 1:1.

Comment: BTW works for me too without issue on W10 x64 AMD 16.12.2

Comment: @MaikKlein dunno if it's helpful, but I ran into this with Vulkano as well (same error in its triangle example, but can run SaschaWillems examples fine). I'm on Ivy Bridge/Linux, which has incomplete Vulkan support, and I feel it might be a shortcoming there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the opportunity to reproduce it on linux(Ubuntu) Mesa13 Intel driver.

The driver seems to return garbage in `VkPresentInfoKHR::pResults`.

If I assign `null_mut` to it instead the program starts to work without issues.

(BTW, your depth image is created as "sparse", which I found odd.)

Comment: Thanks! That should be the error. The spec didn't specify the lifetime for pResults but I assume this might be a problem with the intel driver.

Comment: @MaikKlein What you mean by lifetime? Well, you just need to allocate it yourself to `swapchainCount` size and then keep it alive until the command returns. I don't know Rust that well, but I think you need `present_info_err` allocated to the size (or `null_mut` as I tested it).

Comment: It is currently allocated on the stack and it also writes `Success` on my machine into `present_info_err`. Does `present_info_err` still contain garbage after the `queue_present` call? With "lifetime" I thought that maybe it wouldn't write immediately to pResult but there is no cpu sync and the spec doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: @MaikKlein it is normal return-through-parameter; it would be specified somewhere in the initial chapter for all kinds of parameters generally. ;; Yes, there is non-valid value after `queue_present` returns - that is according to `apidump` I made: http://pastebin.com/RkZBkTH2 ;; So, based on it, the layers think the present failed and do not count the swapchain image as relesed. ;; Probably a driver error then - quick scan of the Mesa source looks to me that they do not write `pResults` at all.

Comment: I had a same problem yesterday and traced it to `unique_objects` validation layer. Without it was correctly written by the driver (nvidia for me) and with it simply didn't touch the content there. So if it was set to success value it stayed as success but if it was some uninitialized value then it was garbage and I got same errors. Reported here: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues/1670. What happened is that this layer copied this array, driver wrote to it's copy but it wasn't copied back to original array hence no writes with it.

Comment: @RippeR Not that it matters now, but the layers at the time did not have the issue. It was really a bug in the Intel Linux Mesa driver: https://github.com/mesa3d/mesa/commit/0fcb92c17dee681bd39c08ddf0abc358a27337c7

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug (not yet fixed) in `unique_objects` validation layer. It's not yet fixed so there isn't really a solution yet. Ticket: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/issues/1670

To workaround that bug you can:

a) Initialize `pResults` array values with something successful (like `VK_RESULT_SUCCESS`) and make sure to also check value returned by `vkQueuePresentKHR()` as this value is already valid one. This will work when they fix it or you won't use validation layers, but for now these values will simply stay as initialized so it won't bother other validation layers.

b) Pass `nullptr` as `pResults`. This won't allow you to inspect specific results per swapchain in the future when they will fix it. If you have only one swapchain, it might be redundant to check both anyway... Though I'd prefer to use `(a)` solution.